# cannot install gem ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems

I'm trying to install gem 'passenger' on my project to use nginx. But when I do

```
$ gem install passenger
```

error comes out like,

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails-devise/gems/passenger-5.0.22/.editorconfig
```

I found that this error is related to my version of ruby and rails. Actually this project started from `ruby version 2.2.2`, and `rails version 4.2.5`. But my ubuntu already has `ruby version 2.2.1`, and `rails version 4.2.4`, this means I installed ruby and rails using rvm at the `/home/ubuntu`.

So I was trying to match the version of my envirnment and my project by reinstalling ruby and rails, using `rvm install ruby-2.2.2`, `gem install rails --version=4.2.5`. But I still get same error.

What I want to do is making my envirnment works fine.(installing gem, matching version correctly using rvm or etc.) Any ideas or document that I can read? As you can see, I'm not good at Linux. So if you have any recommendations, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not related to version of ruby or rails. Could you tell me as which user are you trying to run this command by `whoami` ?

The actual problem seem to be that the file `/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails-devise/gems/passenger-5.0.22/.editorconfig` is not accessible by the current user.

Comment: it comes out `ubuntu`.

Comment: Do I need to install passeger gem on `root`?

Comment: can you try uninstalling passenger and reinstalling. If possible try with a fresh installation on another server to see if issue persists.